# How do I run unit tests stored in my application directory as opposed to in the PHP directory?

Tags: php, windows, unit-testing, windows-vista

I've just installed PHPUnit and wrote a quick class which I saved to C:\PHP and it worked fine.  If however I move the php file containing the test class to the tests directory of my application, it returns the error Class firstTest could not be found in ..

How do I resolve the problem such that it can see the class in the application test directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response - it wasn't the solution I used, but it led me to research that produced an alternative.

What I did was to add my PHP directory (C:\PHP) to the PATH environment variable.  This allowed me to call phpunit from the tests directory of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Check  your config file and ensure that the correct path to the tests dir is given.